# Is the Cytokine Storm the root cause of fatality mechanisms of COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19

A [cytokine storm](https://www.health.com/condition/infectious-diseases/coronavirus/cytokine-storm) means a cell pathway has been turned on, leading to the production of a number of biological mediators (which are kind of like signal transmitters) that cause changes to the body and interfere with normal cell function. Commonly, this means an excessive number of cytokines are released, which create high levels of inflammation in the area of the body being flooded—so much inflammation, even, that it can be fatal.

Is the Cytokine Storm the root cause of fatality mechanisms of COVID-19?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the virus mutates and it is hard to predict what could change,
according to a small [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7532142/) published in the National Center for Biotechnology Information's website, main cause of death is what has always been: Acute respiratory distress syndrome. However, it appears to be related to the cytokine storm:

> Hospitalized patients with severe COVID-19 show high levels of IL-2,
> IL-7, IL-10, granulocyte colony-stimulating factor, tumor necrosis factor, CXCL10, monocyte chemoattractant protein-1, and macrophage inflammatory proteins 1-alpha in serum, suggesting
> that severe COVID-19 is dictated as a cytokine release syndrome (CRS),
> which is a disorder induced by cytokine storms

[source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7527296/)

The cytokine storm often leads to multiorgan failure.